# Android OnClickListener inside ListView Adapter changes another row

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

My List View is like this (4 TextViews in every Row):

[image: I clicked B1 and D3]

When i clicked B1 and D3 they turned grey (that's fine !).
But when I scrolled I found two other TextViews that turned gray too although I didn't click them.[image: I didn't click B11 and D13]

My custom Adapter is:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context cont;
private int count;

public MyAdapter (Context c, int numberOfRow) {
    this.cont = c;
    this.count = numberOfRow;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cont.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);

        ViewHolder hold = new ViewHolder();
        hold.tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        hold.tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        hold.tv3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        hold.tv4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.radio4);

        v.setTag(hold);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    holder.tv1.setText("A " + position);
    holder.tv2.setText("B " + position);
    holder.tv3.setText("C " + position);
    holder.tv4.setText("D " + position);

    OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //Transparent background
            Drawable dr1 = cont.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radio_box);  
                            //Grey background
            Drawable dr2 = cont.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filled_radio_box);

            //Set Transparent background to all
            holder.tv1.setBackground(dr1);
            holder.tv2.setBackground(dr1);
            holder.tv3.setBackground(dr1);
            holder.tv4.setBackground(dr1);

            //Set Grey background only to the TextView which is clicked
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio1:
                holder.tv1.setBackground(dr2);
                break;
            case R.id.radio2:
                holder.tv2.setBackground(dr2);
                break;
            case R.id.radio3:
                holder.tv3.setBackground(dr2);
                break;
            case R.id.radio4:
                holder.tv4.setBackground(dr2);
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    holder.tv1.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    holder.tv2.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    holder.tv3.setOnClickListener(ocl);
    holder.tv4.setOnClickListener(ocl);

    return v;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tv1;
    public TextView tv2;
    public TextView tv3;
    public TextView tv4;
}

}
```

Please do let me know if other code is needed.

**EDIT:** The final solution:
Adapter Class

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tv1;
    public TextView tv2;
    public TextView tv3;
    public TextView tv4;
}

private Context cont;
private int count;
private Problem[] problem;

public MyAdapter (Context c, Problem[] pr) {
    this.cont = c;
    this.problem = pr;
    this.count = pr.length;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cont.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        holder.tv3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        holder.tv4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.radio4);

        final int POS = position;
        OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;

                Problem prb = (Problem) tv.getTag();
                Log.d("onClick", String.valueOf(prb.getPos()));
                Drawable dr1 = cont.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radio_box);
                Drawable dr2 = cont.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filled_radio_box);

                holder.tv1.setBackground(dr1);
                holder.tv2.setBackground(dr1);
                holder.tv3.setBackground(dr1);
                holder.tv4.setBackground(dr1);

                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.radio1:
                    prb.setClicked(1);
                    holder.tv1.setBackground(dr2);
                    break;
                case R.id.radio2:
                    prb.setClicked(2);
                    holder.tv2.setBackground(dr2);
                    break;
                case R.id.radio3:
                    prb.setClicked(3);
                    holder.tv3.setBackground(dr2);
                    break;
                case R.id.radio4:
                    prb.setClicked(4);
                    holder.tv4.setBackground(dr2);
                    break;
                }
                Log.d("onClick", String.valueOf(prb.getClicked()));
            }
        };

        holder.tv1.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        holder.tv2.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        holder.tv3.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        holder.tv4.setOnClickListener(ocl);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    Drawable dr1 = cont.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.radio_box);
    Drawable dr2 = cont.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filled_radio_box);

    Problem pal = problem[position];

    holder.tv1.setText(pal.getA());
    holder.tv2.setText(pal.getB());
    holder.tv3.setText(pal.getC());
    holder.tv4.setText(pal.getD());

    holder.tv1.setBackground(dr1);
    holder.tv2.setBackground(dr1);
    holder.tv3.setBackground(dr1);
    holder.tv4.setBackground(dr1);

    Log.d("log", "pos = " + position + " clicked = " + pal.getClicked());

    switch (pal.getClicked()) {
    case 1:
        holder.tv1.setBackground(dr2);
        break;
    case 2:
        holder.tv2.setBackground(dr2);
        break;
    case 3:
        holder.tv3.setBackground(dr2);
        break;
    case 4:
        holder.tv4.setBackground(dr2);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    holder.tv1.setTag(pal);
    holder.tv2.setTag(pal);
    holder.tv3.setTag(pal);
    holder.tv4.setTag(pal);

    return v;
}   

}
```

Problem Class :

```
public class Problem {

private String A;
private String B;
private String C;
private String D;
private int pos;
private int clicked;

public Problem(int n) {
    this.pos = n;
    this.A = "A " + n;
    this.B = "B " + n;
    this.C = "C " + n;
    this.D = "D " + n;
    this.clicked = -1;
}

public int getClicked() {
    return clicked;
}

public void setClicked(int clicked) {
    this.clicked = clicked;
}

public String getA() {
    return A;
}

public void setA(String a) {
    A = a;
}

public String getB() {
    return B;
}

public void setB(String b) {
    B = b;
}

public String getC() {
    return C;
}

public void setC(String c) {
    C = c;
}

public String getD() {
    return D;
}

public void setD(String d) {
    D = d;
}

public int getPos() {
    return pos;
}

public void setPos(int pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
}
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.. Please debug the code... Your problem occurs on scroll only na?

Comment: i debugged it for hours , at last i posted it in SO.  And yes my problem occurs on scroll.

Comment: @palatok posted try like that and let me know the result..

Comment: @palatok, declare holder at the top of the class and initialize convertView=null and declare postion variable final.I hope this will help.

Comment: @palatok For this you need to take one core class with one boolean variable and check it in getView method..

Comment: Where did you happen to get your "Problems" from? A database?

Comment: @superuserdo, yes i have it in device database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens due to recycling of the views ! Tagging should solve your problem. This is a very common problem, have a look at :

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

[listview checkbox trouble in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489119/listview-checkbox-trouble-in-android)

[ListView Checkbox problem in CustomAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788532/listview-checkbox-problem-in-customadapter)

http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You will need one variable to keep track of the `TextView` which is to be highlighted within a list item.

You can add that variable to either your `Holder` object or use something like a `SparseIntArray` to store the `position` as key and 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 as values to identify which  `TextView` is selected. `0` means no selection. Initially your variable or entry in `SparseIntArray` for that `position` will be `0`.

Next, in the `getView()` lookup the value for `position` as key in `SparseIntArray` and based on that set the background of the `TextView` to mark selection, if any.

This way when you scroll the `ListView`, it will only show selections for List Items which you select and not for others.

Comment: I tried this from this angel, create an integer array inside CustomAdapter class(click = new int[numberOfRow]), then inside OnClickListener i modified this array (click[position] = 1,2,3 or 4, according to which view is clicked), Then in getView() method i colored the corresponding textView to Grey. BUT it did not work.